# Sending multiline text over POST method with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, vb.net, post

I have this function in JQuery:

```
var dataGet = 'LimFile=' + $('#LimFile').val() + '&ProductNumber=' + $('#ArtNoInsert').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/Admin/InsertLim',
                data: dataGet,
                success: function (r) {
                    alert('Product lim entry inserted!');
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert(error)
                }
            })
```

And it is supposed to read multiple lines from LimFile and send it to a string in VB.NET.
Problem is that when I debug it, I see the string is there in full length. And when I split it with vbNewLine, it shows that theres only 1 line, aka nothing is split, like the newlines have been lost.

Comment: Read the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under data. you convert your multiline-data into a single string. Pass it as a object/array instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should never pass a string as `data` but rather an object since in this case jQuery takes care about properly encoding it:

```
var dataGet = {LimFile:  $('#LimFile').val(), ProductNumber: $('#ArtNoInsert').val()};
```

This probably fixes your problem - when POSTing just a plain string containing linebreaks they might break things.

---

Additionally, note that soft linewrapping (e.g. when reaching the end of the line without pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key) is **not** sent to the server. While you could use `wrap="hard"` as @RoryMcCrossan suggested, the better solution is wrapping the text on the server since you cannot trust the client anyway.

Comment: Still, when I split with vbNewLine, its still one large string, I split it like this: limTestValues = csvValues.Split(vbNewLine).ToList

Comment: Are you sure there are and `vbNewLine` (probably `\r\n`) linebreaks in the text? Depending on the OS of the user the text might contain only `\n` linebreaks.

Comment: Hmm, the text does contain them, and now I tried splitting by Environment.Newline, doesn't work eighter =/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just escaping $('#LimFile').val() on the sending side and unescaping it on the receiving side? I find it a lot more "secure".